# Find value in a list of dictionaries without iterating

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

Let's say I have a list `my_list`, and this list is composed of dictionaries.

```
my_list = [{'name': "Julia", 'Hello': 123}, {'name': "Carl", 'Hello': 456}, {'name': "John", 'Hello: 789}]
```

and I want to find the dictionaries in that list with a specific key value

```
def find_dictionary(hello_value):
    # Do the logic
    return my_dictionary
```

for example, find_dictionary(123) should return `{'name': "Julia", 'Hello': 123}`

I know I could iterate, but this is an example, when working with a ton of data, this iteration could make my code slower, and I will need to do this a lot of times... iterating with the data I'm working with currently takes ~20 seconds... is there a way to make it faster, or better, instantaneously?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: You **have** to iterate

Comment: You could preprocess the list to turn it into a dictionary, with your hello values as keys and your dicts as values - but they would have to be unique.

Comment: There is no actual code shown. What do you expect us to improve?

Comment: Unless it is ordered, to find an item in a list, you *cannot do better than a linear search*. You'll have to use another data-structure if you want better performance for lookups. Lists have linear time lookups (unless they are ordered and you can use binary search)

Answer (score 2):

You could preprocess the list to turn it into a dictionary, with your hello values as keys and your dicts as values:

```
my_list = [{'name': "Julia", 'Hello': 123}, {'name': "Carl", 'Hello': 456}, {'name': "John", 'Hello': 789}]

find_dict = {d['Hello']: d for d in my_list}

print(find_dict[123])

# {'name': 'Julia', 'Hello': 123}
```

Building `find_dict` is O(n), each subsequent access is O(1).

There would be a difference with iterating the list, though, if your values are not unique. `find_dict` would retain the last dict containing your value, while you would probably have stopped iterating when finding the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Create another dictionary for reverse lookup

```
>>> my_list = [{'name': "Julia", 'Hello': 123}, {'name': "Carl", 'Hello': 456}, {'name': "John", 'Hello': 789}]
>>> my_dict = {d[k]:d for d in my_list for k in d}
```

Now you can find the dict containing the needed value easily

```
>>> my_dict[123]
{'name': 'Julia', 'Hello': 123}
>>> my_dict['Carl']
{'name': 'Carl', 'Hello': 456}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to iterate to find the dictionary with specific key value.

Comment: While no is a totally valid answer, this is more of a comment. It also doesn't address all the parts in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you have acknowledged a problem like this .

But , its true that you can't do this task in O(1) operation ,or simply putting - one cannot access the specific dictionary from a list without traversing the list.

**So , what's the alternative ?**

If your requirements include no extra space usage then instead of using a linear search go for binary search .This will reduce time complexity drastically from O(n) to O(log n).

If you can allow **extra O(n) space** , you can go for other solutions as they will be more **time efficient** .

**For constant space solution**

Prerequisite : List has to be in sorted order by the hello_values

See the code below to do this :

```
def by_hello_value(elem):
    return elem['Hello']

my_list.sort(key=by_hello_value)
```

Now this list is ready for binary search :

```
def find_dictionary(hello_value):
    l=0
    r=len(my_list)-1
    while(l<=r):
        m = (int)((l+r)/2)
        if(my_list[m]['Hello']==hello_value):
            return my_list[m]
        if(my_list[m]['Hello']<hello_value):
            l=m+1
        else:
            r=m-1
    # return empty dictionary if required hello_valued dictionary is not present in list
    return {}
```

Hope this will help .

And yes,do not forget to share the time taken by this method on your data .You can use  the comment section for that.

Keep asking , keep growing :)

Comment: You could use the bisect module for the binary search.

Comment: Will that make it more time efficient ?

Comment: After seeing a lot of "no"s, I avoided searching the list and started using another method. I don't think it's worth mentioning it, since it solved my problem because the data I was working with helped me do so, and I was already iterating over the lines of a file... I didn't see your answer, and now my whole code is different, so I could not check the time this would take... Thanks anyway.